# xunit .net core 2.1 basic unit test run inside VS2017 fail with time out

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I have build a project from "xUnit Test Project(.Net Core)", the target framework is .Net Core 2.1, once I am trying to run a basic test inside VS 2017 (15.7.4), it fails with the following error after a couple of minutes:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Failed to negotiate protocol. Wait for response timed out.
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.TestRequestSender.CheckVersionWithTestHost()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyExecutionManager.StartTestRun(TestRunCriteria testRunCriteria, ITestRunEventsHandler eventHandler)

I have tried with

> dotnet test

command also but still getting the same error.

I guess it is something related to my proxy setting as I my computer is inside my corporate network which is protected by a proxy.

EDIT:
I have just realized that once I add reference to SUT project, it will cause the issue, but how just adding a project reference could cause this?!

EDIT2:
I have run the tests using the following command:

> dotnet test --diag:log.txt

And can see the following logs in the log file:

> TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 1316, 6, 2018/06/28, 13:32:47.524, 21212669743,
>   vstest.console.dll, Test Runtime launched
>
> TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 1316, 4, 2018/06/28, 13:32:47.533, 21212694192,
>   vstest.console.dll, TestRequestSender.WaitForRequestHandlerConnection:
>   waiting for connection with timeout: 60000
>
> TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 1316, 11, 2018/06/28, 13:32:48.215, 21214464768,
>   vstest.console.dll, SocketServer.OnClientConnected: Client connected
>   for endPoint: 127.0.0.1:51299, starting MessageLoopAsync:
>
> TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 1316, 11, 2018/06/28, 13:32:48.215, 21214465327,
>   vstest.console.dll, TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync: Polling on
>   remoteEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51300 localEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51299